# Dual Boot Problem (Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I had installed in my laptop Windows and Ubuntu, because Windows did not work , I reinstall her. New I can not start ubuntu, when I power on my laptop, it do not ask me which OS I want start and boot automatic Windows. What to do? I am novice :(

Comment: Use this answer to fix your problem : [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always download and use [Resc-a-tux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).

This is a live cd with a primary goal: Restoring grub/installing grub. It's a nice program which I used after windows just removed my grub without asking, and it worked like a charm.

> **Rescatux features:**
>
> Fixes GRUB and GRUB2
>
> Regenerates Debian/Ubuntu grub menues
>
> Check and fix filesystems
>
> Fixes Windows MBR
>
> Blank Windows passwords
>
> Boot Info Script
>
> Change Gnu/Linux password
>
> Regenerate sudoers file
>
> **Extra tools:**
>
> Synaptic
>
> Gparted 0.7

Comment: How to install this program if my modem driver is compatible with only Windows? I am novice, get my only sample solutions.

Comment: this is a cd, and it has everything installed already.